# How to disable aggrid sidebar checkbox

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Everyone
I enable the sidebar of the ag-grid , and the column show in the tool panel , is that possible to set disable for the pivot mode and the checkbox (make it readonly)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent column visibility changes in UI, set `lockVisible: true` in column definitions. The checkboxes will still be there, but they will be disabled.

To hide the pivot switch section from the panel, you need to set the grid `sideBar` property to something like this:

```js
sideBar: SideBarDef = {
    toolPanels: [
      {
        id: 'columns',
        labelDefault: 'Columns',
        labelKey: 'columns',
        iconKey: 'columns',
        toolPanel: 'agColumnsToolPanel',
        toolPanelParams: {
          suppressPivotMode: true, // <-- suppress pivot!
          suppressColumnSelectAll: true
        },
      },
    ],
    defaultToolPanel: 'columns',
  };
```

See more information about configuring the panel in [docs here](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/tool-panel-columns).

Comment: one more question , when I try lockVisibility: true , but its no work , may I know what page should I refer to

Comment: @mres, if you mean ag-grid docs, it's [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/column-moving/#lock-visible).

Comment: Actually I just noticed it's not `lockVisibility`, but `lockVisible` instead :) Sorry about that.